# Strategy for proving that Dedekind cuts satisfy the property of trichotomy

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that given Dedekind cuts $\alpha, \beta$, exactly one of $\alpha < \beta$, $\beta < \alpha$, and $\alpha = \beta$ holds.

I'm only interested in the proof strategy, because once I have the strategy in mind, I think I can prove it. The idea I have is the following. I need to show:

(i) at least one of $\alpha < \beta$, $\beta < \alpha$, and $\alpha = \beta$ holds.

(ii) only one holds, i.e., two cannot hold simultaneously.

To prove (i), I believe I can proceed as follows. I can prove that if $\alpha \nless \beta$ and $\beta \nless \alpha$ then $\alpha = \beta$. Then the argument has the form:
\begin{align*}
& (\neg (\alpha < \beta) \wedge \neg (\beta < \alpha)) \implies (\alpha = \beta) \\
& \equiv \neg (\neg (\alpha < \beta) \wedge \neg (\beta < \alpha)) \lor (\alpha = \beta) \\
& \equiv (\alpha < \beta) \lor (\beta < \alpha) \lor (\alpha = \beta). 
\end{align*}

To prove (ii), I think I have to prove that if $\alpha < \beta$ holds, then $\beta < \alpha$ and $\alpha = \beta$ doesn't hold; if $\beta < \alpha$, then $\alpha < \beta$ and $\alpha = \beta$ cannot hold; and if $\alpha = \beta$, then neither $\alpha < \beta$ or $\beta < \alpha$ hold.

I'm interested in whether there is some symmetry to the above argument. If I prove the first statement when $\alpha < \beta$, that seems exactly symmetric to proving the second statement where $\beta < \alpha$, interchanging labels of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So I could do in this two instead of three steps.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this proof strategy.

Comment: What is your definition of inequality of Dedekind cuts? The problem is an immediate consequence of the definition.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The definition I have is $\alpha < \beta$ if $\alpha$ is a proper subset of $\beta$. It seems to me that the fact that two cannot hold simultaneously follows immediately, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation $<$ on set $S$ is trichotomous $\iff{}$ for all $\alpha{},\beta{}\in{}S$, one and only one of the following is true:

1. $\alpha{}=\beta{}$
2. $\alpha{}<\beta{}$
3. $\beta{}<\alpha{}$

In your case, $<$ is the proper subset relation. It is clear that no more than one of 1, 2, 3 can be true. If you need clarification on this point do not hesitate to ask.

How can we prove that at least one of 1, 2, 3 is true?

Suppose 1 and 2 are false. Then if we can prove that 3 must be true, we are done*.

Note that $\alpha{},\beta{}\neq{}\varnothing{}$ by the definition of cut. Given that 1 and 2 are false, we have $\alpha{}\not\subset{}\beta{}$. Thus there exists $q\in{}\mathbb{Q}$ with $q\in{}\alpha{}$ and $q\notin{}\beta{}$. Now consider $q'\in{}\beta{}$. If $q'>q$ then $q\in{}\beta{}$ by the definition of cut, which is a contradiction. Therefore $q'<q$, which forces $q'\in{}\alpha{}$ by the same part of the definition of cut. As $q'$ was an arbitrary element of $\beta{}$, this shows that $\beta{}\subset{}\alpha{}$. The fact that $q\in{}\alpha{}$ and $q\notin{}\beta{}$ forces $\beta{}<\alpha{}$.

*This is a general proof technique; in two-valued logic, if we have $n$ statements with $n\in{}\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq{}2$, then to show that at least one of the $n$ statements is true it suffices to assume $n-1$ of the statements are false and then to prove that the last statement must be true.

Comment: This is very helpful. I would appreciate more clarification on how we know that exactly one is true. Also, can we say that in some sense $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ is a "subspace" of a "suborder" of $(\mathbb{R}, <)$? This order on $\mathbb{Q}$ is surely the order on $\mathbb{R}$ "restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$" in some sense.

Comment: We know that no more than one of the statements can be true (if this is unclear, please tell me and I will explain). So there are only two possibilities: either one statement of 1,2,3 is true or none of them are true. If we assume the first two statements are false, then we can prove that the third is true. Thus there are two cases: 1) either the first two statements are NOT false (i.e., at least one is true, and from the above only one can be true) or 2) or the first two statements ARE false and we can prove that the third is true. So in all cases, one and only one statement is true.

Comment: There is a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^*$, where the latter is the set of "rational cuts", i.e., the cuts which correspond to a rational number (e.g., $\frac{3}{4}^*=\{q|q\in{}\mathbb{Q}\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,q<\frac{3}{4}\}$). It is possible to prove that this bijection preserves addition and multiplication (is an "isomorphism"). An order like $(\mathbb{Q}^*,<)$ is a relation on $\mathbb{Q}^*$, a subset of $\mathbb{Q}^*\times{}\mathbb{Q}^*$, i.e., a set of ordered pairs whose entries come from $\mathbb{Q}^*$. This is a proper subset of $(\mathbb{R},<)$.

Comment: Finally, yes, $\mathbb{Q}^*$ can be viewed as a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}^*$.